# How to obtain a MongoDb collection in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

There are two different methods to obtain a reference to a MongoDB collection - both of them are used throughout the official documentation.

There is

```
var mycollection = db.collection('mycollection)'
```

and there is

```
db.collection('mycollection', function(err, collection){
   //use collection
}
```

I tend to use the second one because it is consistent with "db.createCollecion(collection, callback)"

What is the difference between these methods?

Is there any database interaction when using these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/db.js#L456) for `Database`, currently around line 456, you'll see that the only difference between the two in the way you've used them is how the collection object is returned. If you specify a callback, then it's returned that way, otherwise, it's returned as the value to the function. If you set the options however and specifically the option `strict` to `true`, you need to use the callback. When `strict` is set to `true`, the collection is verified before continuing (asynchronously).

Given that collections can be created dynamically (and usually are upon first use), there often isn't need to use `strict` mode.

So, it's really matter of personal coding preference otherwise. There is normally no activity to the database when creating a Collection object via: `db.collection('collectionname')` with the exception I mentioned above.